# Cannot put <meta property="og:title"> of facebook like button in user control of asp.net mvc c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented the Like Facebook Button in my user control. This is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>
                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                
            </script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<%:FBUrl%>" data-send="true" data-width="450" 
data-show-faces="true">
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to add this block on the top of my user control :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Welcome to site!" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

But it doesn't appeared the title either the description while I click on the like box.

Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have two user controls.

One for including in the `<head>` section that defines the og: tags.

And the other user control that you can include in the `<body>` that has the like html.

I would strongly suggest using the HTML5 version of the plugin code rather than the xfbml version.